# Some questions about a sequence and concepts i developed to find its nth term.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, integer-sequences

So I developed these concepts and they seem to be useful to find nth term of certain types of sequences. I have only given definitions and rules and other things, i decided not to write what led me to each concepts since that would be too long.

## Definitions and Rules

$\left\langle\begin{array}{c}a_1 \\ a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b$ is in 'normal form' when:

1. $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq b,$
2. $0 \leq a_1\leq a_2,$
3. $b \geq 1, \text{ where } a_1, a_2, b \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$

Rules to convert $\left\langle\begin{array}{c}a_1 \\ a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b$ into normal form:

1. $\left\langle\begin{array}{c}a_1 \\ a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b = \left\langle\begin{array}{c}0\\a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b$ if $a_1<0$ and $0 \leq a_2 \leq b$.
2. $\left\langle\begin{array}{c}a_1 \\ a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b = \left\langle\begin{array}{c}a_1 \\ b\end{array}\right\rangle_b$ if $a_2 > b$ and $0 \leq a_1 \leq b$.
3. $\left\langle\begin{array}{c}a_1 \\ a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b = \left\langle\begin{array}{c}0\\ b\end{array}\right\rangle_b$ if $a_1 < 0$ and $a_2 > b$.
4. $\left\langle\begin{array}{c}a_1 \\ a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b = \langle\rangle$ if $a_1 > a_2$.
5. $\left\langle\begin{array}{c}a_1 \\ a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b = \langle\rangle$ if $a_1, a_2 < 0$ or $a_1, a_2 > b$.

$\left\langle a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_k\right\rangle_b$ where $a_i\in \{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ is in 'normal form' when: $0 \leq a_i \leq b$ for $i \in\{1,2,3, \ldots, k\}$.

To convert $\left\langle a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_k\right\rangle_b$ into normal form, remove all $a_i$ which are $<0$ or $> b$.

For example: $\langle 2,3,7\rangle_5=\langle 2,3\rangle_5$.

## Operations

1. $\left\langle a_1\right\rangle_b=\left\langle\begin{array}{c}a_1 \\ a_1\end{array}\right\rangle_b$.
2. $\left\langle a_1\right\rangle_b + \left\langle a_2\right\rangle_b + \left\langle a_3\right\rangle_b + \ldots + \left\langle a_k\right\rangle_b = \left\langle a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k\right\rangle_b$.
3. $\left\langle a_1\right\rangle_b + \left\langle a_1+1\right\rangle_b + \left\langle a_1+2\right\rangle_b + \ldots + \left\langle a_2\right\rangle_b = \left\langle\begin{array}{c}a_1 \\ a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b$.
4. $\left\langle a_1\right\rangle_b + \left\langle a_1\right\rangle_b + \ldots(n\ times)= n\left\langle a_1\right\rangle_b$.
5. $n\left\langle a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k\right\rangle_b=n\left\langle a_1\right\rangle_b + n\left\langle a_2\right\rangle_b + \ldots + n\left\langle a_k\right\rangle_b$.
6. $\left\langle a_1\right\rangle_b - \left\langle a_1\right\rangle_b = \langle\rangle$.
7. $\left\langle a_1\right\rangle_b \pm \langle\rangle = \left\langle a_1\right\rangle_b$.
8. $n\left[a\left\langle\begin{array}{c}a_1 \\ a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b \pm c\left\langle\begin{array}{c}c_1 \\ c_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b \pm d\left\langle\begin{array}{c}d_1 \\ d_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b \pm \ldots\right]$
   $= na\left\langle\begin{array}{c}a_1 \\ a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b \pm nc\left\langle\begin{array}{c}c_1 \\ c_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b \pm nd\left\langle\begin{array}{c}d_1 \\ d_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b \pm \ldots$.

## Functions

1. $\left\langle\begin{array}{l}a_1 \\ a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b(0)=\left\langle\begin{array}{l}a_1 \\ a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b$.
2. $\left\langle a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k\right\rangle_b(0)=\left\langle a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k\right\rangle_b$.
3. $\left\langle\begin{array}{l}a_1 \\ a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b(n)=\left\langle\begin{array}{l}a_1-n \\ a_2-n\end{array}\right\rangle_b+\left\langle\begin{array}{l}a_1+n \\ a_2+n\end{array}\right\rangle_b$ where $n \in \{1,2,3, \ldots\}$.
4. $\left\langle a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k\right\rangle_b(n)=\left\langle a_1-n, a_2-n, \ldots, a_k-n\right\rangle_b + \left\langle a_1+n, a_2+n, \ldots, a_k+n\right\rangle_b$.
5. $\left\langle\begin{array}{l} a_1 \\ a_2 \end{array}\right\rangle_b\left(n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_m\right) $

$= \left\langle\begin{array}{l} a_1-n_1 \\ a_2-n_1 \end{array}\right\rangle_b\left(n_2, n_3, \ldots, n_m\right)+\left\langle\begin{array}{l} a_1+n_1 \\ a_2+n_1 \end{array}\right\rangle_b\left(n_2, n_3, \ldots, n_m\right)$.
6. $\left\langle a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k\right\rangle_b\left(n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_m\right)$

$=\left\langle a_1-n_1, a_2-n_1, \ldots, a_k-n _1\right\rangle_b\left( n_2, n_3, \ldots, n_m \right)$
$+\left\langle a_1+n_1, a_2+n_1, \ldots, a_k+n _1\right\rangle_b\left( n_2, n_3, \ldots, n_m \right)$.

## Value

The value of $\left\langle\begin{array}{l}a_1 \\ a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b$ or any other expression of similar type, denoted as '$|\left\langle\begin{array}{l}a_1 \\ a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b|$', is only calculated when it is in normal form.

Here are rules to calculate values of different expressions and their functions:

1. $|\langle\rangle|=0$
2. $|\left\langle\begin{array}{l}a_1 \\ a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b| = a_2-a_1+1$
3. $|\left\langle a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k\right\rangle_b|=k$
4. $|\left\langle a_1\right\rangle_b+\left\langle a_2\right\rangle_b+\ldots+\left\langle a_k\right\rangle_b| = |\left\langle a_1\right\rangle_b|+|\left\langle a_2\right\rangle_b|+\ldots+|\left\langle a_k\right\rangle_b|$
5. $|\left\langle\begin{array}{l} a_1 \\ a_2 \end{array}\right\rangle_b\left(n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_m\right)|$
   $= |\left\langle\begin{array}{l} a_1-n_1 \\ a_2-n_1 \end{array}\right\rangle_b\left(n_2, n_3, \ldots, n_m\right)|+|\left\langle\begin{array}{l} a_1+n_1 \\ a_2+n_1 \end{array}\right\rangle_b\left(n_2, n_3, \ldots, n_m\right)|$
6. $|\left\langle a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k\right\rangle_b\left(n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_m\right)|$

$=|\left\langle a_1-n_1, a_2-n_1, \ldots, a_k-n _1\right\rangle_b\left( n_2, n_3, \ldots, n_m \right)|$

$+|\left\langle a_1+n_1, a_2+n_1, \ldots, a_k+n _1\right\rangle_b\left( n_2, n_3, \ldots, n_m \right)|$

## Why All this?

These concepts are the results of my research on a sequence I discovered a few months ago. The sequence $N_A$ is defined as follows:
'Let $A \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$ be a $k$-digit number in base-10, then we can represent $A$ as $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k)$ where $a_i$ is the $i$-th digit from left and $a_1 \neq 0$ except when $A=0$. Let $S(A) = \{ (b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_{k+1}) : |b_i - b_{i+1}| = a_i, 1 \leq i \leq k, b_i \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, 9\} \}$ then $N_A=$ number of elements in $S(A)$.' For example, when $A=0$ then $S(0)= \{ (0,0), (1,1), (2,2), \ldots, (9,9) \}$ and $N_A= 10$.

It turns out $N_A= |\left\langle\begin{array}{l} 0 \\ 9 \end{array}\right\rangle_9\left(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k\right)|$, for example $ |\left\langle\begin{array}{l} 0 \\ 9 \end{array}\right\rangle_9\left(0\right)|= 9-0+1=10$.

Here is an image of sequence $\frac{N_A}{2}$ from $A=0$ to $A=9999$ displayed in a 100 by 100 table,even odd highlighted:
[image]

Here is an example using some concepts (sorry for handwriting):
[image]

## Question

I would like to know you guys' thoughts on this, like how do you see this from a higher mathematical perspective ? Is it connected to some other concepts or does something similar exists already? Is there some branch of mathematics which study these type of concepts or something similar?

I have noticed that $\frac{|\left\langle\begin{array}{l} 0 \\ 9 \end{array}\right\rangle_9\left(a_1, a_2, \ldots,a_{k-1}, a_k\right)|}{2}$ is even or odd iff $\frac{|\left\langle\begin{array}{l} 0 \\ 9 \end{array}\right\rangle_9\left(a_1, a_2, \ldots,a_{k-1}, 10-a_k\right)|}{2}$ is even or odd, i.e., they have same parity. I have proved this using just the concepts i developed but i would like to know if this sequence and theorem can be reframed and solved from a different perspective, like a combinatorial approach or generating functions or something else.

## Some findings

Here is an image of another interesting finding:
[image]

Comment: "Is it connected to some other concepts or does something similar exists already?" - yes. The vast majority of it seems to be match the concept that $\langle a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k\rangle_b = \{a_1, \dots, a_k\}$ truncated to throw out anything $< 0$ or $>b$, and $\left\langle\begin{array}{c}a_1\\a_2\end{array}\right\rangle_b$ is just a shorthand for $\{a_1, a_1+1, \dots, a_2-1, a_2\}$. $+$ is $\cup$ (not quite, this is where it differs), and $(n)$ denotes the union of translations by $n$ and $-n$, and value is just the cardinality of the set.

Comment: @PaulSinclair i see, at first i also thought of it as collection of numbers or set but made different notations since sets can't have same elements twice and i often encountered collection of numbers with repetition, and as you said union is different from + and thats why multiplying sets by a number like 2 or 3 would not be meaningful but i noticed if i use my notation where multiplication is defined finding values becomes simple. Overall i think the new notations i made is neater to study this sequence.

Comment: "sets can't have the same elements twice" - that is the difference I mentioned. What you have are sometimes called "multisets", but I do not believe the terminology can be considered standard. We usually treat them as sequences (i.e., elements indexed by integers) and just ignore the ordering of the indices. Your multiplying is a natural concept for multisets. The only issue is that in cases as here where the elements are numbers, the multiplying notation is already in common use with a different meaning (multiplication of each element by the coefficient). But this is acceptable if explained.

Comment: Your + is called the "disjoint union" and is symbolized as $\sqcup$ `\sqcup`. However, all your notations are acceptable. Mathematicians regularly apply irregular meanings to common notations. The practice is acceptable as long as you explain those meanings when you use them, and the common meaning isn't needed in the same text. It only becomes an issue when the new usage also starts to become common, and the notation/terminology becomes ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful explanations.

Comment: Actually, a better way of modelling multisets than sequences is as a "weighted set". That is, a "universe" set $S$ and a function from $S$ into the natural numbers: $A^* : S \to \Bbb N$.  Call $A^*$ the "count function" of the multiset $A$. For $x \in S$, the value $A^*(x)$ is the number of times the element $x$ is in $A$. Under this interpretation, Your $A + B$ is exactly the result of adding the count functions: $(A+B)^*(x) = A(x) + B(x)$, and coefficient multiplication is similar: $(nA)^*(x) = nA^*(x)$. $A(n)$ and your range notation are peculiar to your case, but the rest is more general.

Answer (score 1):

Your system of equations can be seen as involving a binary operation $$\circ_b:\mathbb{I}\times\mathbb{Z}^*\to\mathbb{N}$$
indexed by the positive integer base $b$ of a numeral system with digit-set $\{0\,\dots\,b-1\}$, where $\mathbb{I}$ is the set of finite *intervals* of integers, and $\mathbb{Z}^*$ is the set of finite *tuples* of integers. This binary operation is completely specified by the following four equations:

$$\begin{align}
[\,] \circ_b (T) &= 0\tag{1a}\\
I\circ_b(\ ) &= \text{card}(\ I_b\ )\tag{1b}\\
I\circ_b(0,\, T) &= I\circ_b (T)\tag{1c}\\
I\circ_b(p,\, T) &= (I_b-p)\circ_b(T)\,+\,(I_b-p)\circ_b(T),\quad p\in\{1,2,3,\dots\}\tag{1d} 
\end{align}$$

where $I\in\mathbb{I}$ and $[\,]$ is the empty interval; $I_b=I\cap[0\ ..\ b-1]$; $(T)\in\mathbb{Z}^*$ and $(\,)$ is the empty tuple; $I-p$, (resp. $I+p$) denotes the interval $I$ shifted left (resp. right) by distance $p$.

A common notation for integer intervals (analogous to real intervals) is $[x,y]=\{x,x+1,\dots,y-1,y\}$, with the convention that this denotes the empty set when $x>y.$ Thus we can conveniently write $[x,y]_b$ instead of the rather unwieldy vertical array angle brackets $\left\langle\begin{array}{c}x \\ y\end{array}\right\rangle_{b-1}.$

From your definition of the sequence $(N_A)_{A=0,1,2,\dots},$ it is clear that generally, ${[0,b-1]\circ_b(T)}$ is equal to the number of base-$b$ digit sequences for which $(T)$ is their first-(forward or backward)-differences, and that half this number is equal to the number of base-$b$ digit sequences for which $(T)$ is their first-*forward*-differences.

Consequently, the number of sequences having a given tuple as their first-differences is equal to the number of sequences having the *reverse* of that tuple as their first-differences (since the same differences will simply occur in reverse order); i.e.
$$\begin{align}[0,b-1]\circ_b \text{reverse}(T) &=[0,b-1]\circ_b(T).\tag{2}\\[2ex]
\end{align}$$

**Claim**: For any even base $b$, ${[0,b-1]\circ_b(a_1,...,a_k)\over 2}, {[0,b-1]\circ_b(a_1,...,\overline{ a_k})\over 2}$ and ${[0,b-1]\circ_b(\overline{ a_1},...,a_k)\over 2}$ have the same parity, where $\overline{a}=(b-a)\bmod b.$

EDIT: The following is a sketch of how my originally incomplete proof of this claim might be completed, however tediously.

I think a proof of this claim can be obtained as follows. Generally, we have
$$I\circ_b(\dots,a)=I^{(1)}\circ_b(a) + \dots + I^{(k)}\circ_b(a)\\
I\circ_b(\dots,\overline{a})=I^{(1)}\circ_b(\overline{a}) + \dots + I^{(k)}\circ_b(\overline{a})$$
where the exact same intervals $I^{(j)}$ (arising from the "$\dots$" part of the tuple) occur in both equations; hence, noting that $\overline{0}=0$ and $\overline{p}=b-p$ for a positive base-$b$ digit $p$, the claim is established if we show that
${[x,y]\circ_b(p)\over 2}$ and ${[x,y]\circ_b(\overline{p})\over 2}$ have the same parity for any positive base-$b$ digit $p$ and any of the intervals $[x,y]\subseteq[0,b-1]$ occurring among the $I^{(j)}$.

E.g., for $[x,y]=[0,b-1]$,
$${[0,b-1]\circ_b(p)\over 2}={[0,b-1-p] + [p,b-1]\over 2}=b-p=\overline{p}$$
and
$${[0,b-1]\circ_b(\overline{p})\over 2}={[0,b-1-\overline{p}] + [\overline{p},b-1]\over 2}=b-\overline{p}={p}$$
must have the same parity, because an even $b$ implies $p$ and $b-p$ have the same parity. Completing the proof by this approach will involve separate treatment of the various cases of $([x,y]\pm p) \cap[0,...,b-1].$

---

In your third image, concerning the sequence $N_1,N_{11},N_{111},\dots$, I notice that the computations do not use same functions as in your preceding image; that is, rather than having
$$\left\langle\begin{array}{c}x \\ y\end{array}\right\rangle_{9} (1,T) =\left\langle\begin{array}{c}x-1 \\ y-1\end{array}\right\rangle_{9} (T)+ \left\langle\begin{array}{c}x+1 \\ y+1\end{array}\right\rangle_{9} (T)$$
the table appears to use instead
$$\left\langle\begin{array}{c}x \\ y\end{array}\right\rangle_{9} (1,T) =\left\langle\begin{array}{c}x-1 \\ y+1\end{array}\right\rangle_{9}(T)+ \left\langle\begin{array}{c}x+1 \\ y-1\end{array}\right\rangle_{9}(T)$$
with no explanation. In fact the RHSs can (tediously) be shown equivalent *only for tuples of form $(1,1,\dots,1)$*, which is of course the stated context.

---

Here's a Python program I used to confirm my results (and yours):

```
def intersect(P, b=10):
    # P is a pair of integers denoting the interval [P(0),P(1)]
    # intersect(P) is the intersection of [P(0),P(1)] and [0,b-1]
    return [max(P[0],0), min(P[1],b-1)]

def f(P, L, b=10):
    # returns P o_b L
    # P is empty or a pair of integers
    # L is a possibly-empty list of integers
    if P==[] or P[0]>P[1]:
        return 0
    if L==[]:
        P = intersect(P, b)
        return max(0, P[1]-P[0]+1)
    elif L[0]==0:
        return f(P, L[1:], b)
    else:
        P = intersect(P, b)  # intersect the interval, then shift it by -L[0] and +L[0] 
        return f([P[0]-L[0], P[1]-L[0]], L[1:], b) + f([P[0]+L[0], P[1]+L[0]], L[1:], b)
```

Comment: Can you please explain how does showing " 
${[0,b-1]\circ_b(p)\over 2}$ and ${[0,b-1]\circ_b(\overline{p})\over 2}$ have the same parity for any positive base-$b$ digit." proves the claim ? I don't get it.

Comment: @Shahrukh You've caught a major omission, thanks.  I think this approach can be salvaged (as now edited), but it may be tedious to treat the various cases.  I'll try to do so as time permits, unless you or someone can spot a fatal flaw.

Comment: ${[x,y]\circ_b(p)}$ and ${[x,y]\circ_b(\overline{p})}$ can in some cases be odd so dividing can't be done and a new approach is needed. I think that would be to prove that in the last step ,values occur in pairs and then prove that ${[x,y]\circ_b(p)}$ and ${[x,y]\circ_b(\overline{p})}$ have same parity.